# NoClassDefFoundError: : org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, log4j, websphere

In my java application deployed on WebSphere 8.5 and I run into this error even though I have below log4j in my maven dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

I did run a `dependency:tree` and I can see that it is being pulling in as
 `+-log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile` which is what I would expect to see in the tree result so I can confirm that it is in the classpath.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace details ?

Comment: ClassNotFoundException means the class is completely missing, but NoClassDefFoundError is subtly different; it was found but was likely loaded by a different classloader in the classloader hierarchy that's not accessible to the referencing code. This is a pretty common error on app servers where the app server itself provides different (or the same) versions of jars to what your app is using. The usual fix is to either use the jar that's provided, or configure your app to use what is packaged in your ear/war (the config for this varies by app server)

Comment: As a clarification... NoClassDefFoundError doesn't necessarily mean the class was found - it's often (most often, in my experience) caused by an underlying ClassNotFoundException. But it can mean other things as well - in particular, the class could have failed static initialization. Regardless, a NoClassDefFoundError is essentially never the "real" problem - you'll want to drill down the stack trace to find the root "Caused by" exception.

Comment: I made sure to add the dependency in only my JAR which uses it. I removed all other occurrences of the dependency and also added  `<exclusion>` list whenever it is being pulled in transitively. This is the recent log  
 https://pastebin.com/n2sbSbyC

Comment: Apologies if this sounds like an "is your computer turned on?" question... but is the jar actually in the EAR/WAR that gets deployed to the server? Just trying to determine whether it's a build problem or a class loading problem. The stack trace indicates that the class was indeed not found (a ClassNotFoundException is the root cause), and the stack trace includes WebSphere application class loaders (so it seems like the right loaders were used).

Comment: @Jarid Yes. The log4j dependency is in the JAR since only this JAR has classes that use log4j. The JAR is in the EAR which is deployed to the Websphere. In the EAR I added the JAR but what I did was added log4j to the exclusino list as below:
`<dependency>
   <groupId>com</groupId>
   <artifactId>MySite-com-Util</artifactId>
   <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Websphere has a wierd class loading parameter called parent-first/parent-last:

https://www.xtivia.com/understanding-websphere-appserver-class-loaders/

Find the value and try changing it in the websphere admin console.